# What is the system color of disabled text?

Tags: .net, winforms, text, colors

I have a control that doesn't have Disabled/Enabled support for text, so I need to build that into it.

The question is simply this: If I want to pick the right system color so that this control has the same color of its disabled text as neighboring disabled labels, which system color should I pick? I've tried a few and none seem right, they're either a bit too light or a bit too dark.

In other words, suppose the ForeColor property is present, what should I write here:

```
myDefunctLabel.ForeColor = SystemColors.???;
```

Comment: Doesn't disabled text have some kind of shadow effect and thus more than a single color? At least I remember it being like that in older versions of windows.

Comment: I don't have anything like that here. In any case, it is *somewhat* better than the old "default", which was that disabled control would still show up as stark black. I'll keep researching this and test this on some more computers, but I'll start off with Adam's answer, ControlDark.

Comment: If SystemColors.GrayText is not the color you expect, it is because your current theme defined it differently. See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpf/archive/2010/11/30/systemcolors-reference.aspx

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`SystemColors.ControlDark` looks good on my screen.  And this is from actually trying them.  I tried most of the others and the shade is wrong.

But according to the docs, `GrayText` is the one you need.  Bear in mind I tried my sample on Windows 7 with Aero enabled, not sure if screen themes plays silly with the colouring here.

Comment: I agree `ControlDark` is also better than `GrayText` - on Windows 7 with Aero disabled (Basic theme)

Answer (score 10):

You're looking for [SystemColors.GrayText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.systemcolors.graytext.aspx).

Comment: Hmm, that means there's something somewhere that overrides it. That color is slightly darker than a nearby disabled label. But I'll stick to that and figure out why my labels are lighter then :)

Comment: SystemColors.ControlDark works for me, I tried GrayText and it looks off.  That's not to say it's not the correct answer, just that the colouring looks different.

Comment: @Lasse according to the colour picker in Paint.NET, ControlDark is the same as disabled per pixel.  The MSDN docs don't back this up mind you.

Comment: It looked right on my screen. That *might* indicate I should close this question as too-localized, but anyway. I don't like to moderate my own content, so if you agree perhaps a flag is in order.

Comment: This answer is correct according to the docs - it's just that if you use this color, your control won't match the Windows controls, which use a different color.

Answer (score 4):

System.Drawing.SystemColors.GrayText should be it.

Answer (score 0):

Probably [SystemColors.Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.systemcolors.control.aspx) will give a color which is required by you or probably [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.systemcolors.graytext.aspx)