# Actual text color on disabled button

Tags: vb.net, button, colors, disabled-control

VB2012: I am creating a button control and inheriting from the .NET button. Taking the base from here https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jfoscoding/2005/11/10/building-a-splitbutton/  Since I am repainting the button I have to introduce some code to change the button text when disabled.

So from past experience I went right away with `SystemColors.GrayText`. But comparing that to a normal .NET button, the color when disabled seems a bit off. After experimenting the one that comes pretty close is `SystemColors.ControlDark`. I can't find this documented anywhere. Am I doing this poroperly?

Comment: FYI there are about a dozen split button on CodeProject

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7766584/1070452

Comment: Yeah I know. They didn't do what I wanted and some were just plain overkill. This one was exactly what I needed plus I could learn while I was adding stuff to it.

Comment: Much appreciated. I read that SO article too but it doesn't say why that is the case. In my situation I am running Win7 with Windows Classic so was assuming GrayText would do it but no cigar.

Comment: If you are repainting the entire button then you have to do that on your own...no?

Answer (score 1):

After writing a very clunky pixel peeping program, it seems that the forecolor is 160,160,160 and the backcolor is 204,204,204. The windows ClearType font smoothing made things a bit difficult, life is never simple eh?

so you would need to set the colours something like this

```
    Me.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(160, 160, 160)
    Me.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(204, 204, 204)
```

or at least thats what they are on my Windows 10 pc with the standard theme anyways.

Answer (score 0):

For something like this, [Reference Source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/) is your friend.  If you follow down through the calls, you'll see that the `System.Windows.Forms.Button` class eventually calls the `ButtonBaseAdapter.DrawText` method to perform the actual drawing of the text on the button.  The call stack looks like this:

- `System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.OnPaint`
- `System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.PaintControl`

  - The `PaintControl` method calls `Adapter.Paint`.  `Adapter` is a property which returns the current button's drawing adapter.  The adapter it returns depends on the style (viz. flat, popup, standard).  If it's a standard style button, then it calls the `Button.CreateStandardAdapter` method which returns a `ButtonStandardAdapter`, so that's the one which will be used by the `PaintControl` method.  The `ButtonStandardAdapter.Paint` method is implemented by its base class, though, so that's the one that gets called.
- `System.Windows.Forms.ButtonInternal.ButtonBaseAdapter.Paint`
- `System.Windows.Forms.ButtonInternal.ButtonStandardAdapter.PaintUp`
- `System.Windows.Forms.ButtonInternal.ButtonStandardAdapter.PaintWorker`
- `System.Windows.Forms.ButtonInternal.ButtonBaseAdapter.PaintField`
- `System.Windows.Forms.ButtonInternal.ButtonBaseAdapter.DrawText`

In that `DrawText` method, you'll see that it draws the disabled text like this:

```cs
if (disabledText3D && !Control.Enabled) {
    r.Offset(1, 1);
    using (SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(colors.highlight)) {
        g.DrawString(Control.Text, Control.Font, brush, r, stringFormat);
        r.Offset(-1, -1);
        brush.Color = colors.buttonShadow;
        g.DrawString(Control.Text, Control.Font, brush, r, stringFormat);
    }
}
```

So, first, it draws the text, offset `(1, 1)`, with `colors.highlight`, and then it draws it again, but this time offset `(-1, -1)` with `colors.buttonShadow`.  The `colors` variable is a reference to a `ColorData` object.  If you follow the code, you'll see that the `ColorData` is being created by the `System.Windows.Forms.ButtonInternal.ButtonBaseAdapter.ColorOptions.Calculate` method.  The colors it returns are dependent on some system settings, such normal vs. high-contrast mode.  But, for a standard situation, it looks like the colors it returns are:

```
ColorData.highlight = SystemColors.ControlLightLight
ColorData.buttonShadow = SystemColors.ControlDark
```