# How to change the back color when the combobox is disabled. it looks odd when it is disabled?

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms

I have a combobox. When it is disabled, it is not visible correctly. How to overcome this issue?

Comment: Hi, you can start looking here -> https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 1):

Change the CanSelect property to False instead of disabling it.

```
combobox1.CanSelect = False
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a trivial thing to do, you can search forum for similar threads, such as [Actual text color on disabled button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37596515/actual-text-color-on-disabled-button)

One good workaround is to put a textbox before the ComboBox and insert selected value there. You can then use

```
Me.TextBox1.ReadOnly = True
```

Instead of:

```
Me.ComboBox.Enabled = False
```

You can change the value in textbox when ComboBox is changed:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    Me.TextBox1.Text = Me.ComboBox1.GetItemText(Me.ComboBox1.SelectedItem)
End Sub
```