# Symbolic names for WPF system colors?

Tags: wpf, colors, system-setting

Where can I get symbolic names for WPF "system" colors? I tried `SystemColors` but the names do not tell me much, for example I don't see an entry for disabled label text color.

And I am looking for something along such lines -- enabled button text color, enabled button background color, disabled button text color, and so on.

Comment: Could you maybe tell us why you need them? System controls share the `SystemColors.Control*` brushes so you will not find any specific SystemColors for button, textblock, etc. If you make your own control, just use those.

Comment: @Freggar, because I set `red`, then `green` and then I need my label looks like disabled one. If I set `gray` it would maybe work for default theme, but if the theme is different `gray` would not be valid as disabled color. So I need something like `my_label.Foreground = SystemColors.Disabled....` but I cannot find anything relevant. I see those `ControlXXX` entries but again nothing related to disabled colors.

Comment: You probably want to use `SystemColors.ControlDark`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7766584/what-is-the-system-color-of-disabled-text

Comment: Btw you can do some neat trick in the GUI designer. Right click on the label (in Design view) "Edit Style" -> "Edit a copy". This will show you the different brushes that the label uses.  You will find that the label actually uses `SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey` for disabled text...

Answer (score 0):

You can access system colors with x:Static:

```
<TextBox Text="Looks like disabled text" Foreground="{x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrush}"/>
```

It makes sens also always to take a look to the default styles and templates [Control Styles and Templates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970773(v=vs.100).aspx) since a lot of colors are defined there.

Here are available [SystemColors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.SystemColors%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).